# Model does not create a verion after deleting a foreign key model object (django-reversion)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, audit, django-reversion

I have 2 classes:

```
class ContactInternal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
SysAppApp = apps.get_app_config('SysApp')
SysAppModel = SysAppApp.models
reversion.register(ContactInternal, follow=["fk_contactinternal_sysapp"])
reversion.register(SysAppModel)

# SysApp from another app called 'SysApp'
class SysApp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    internalcontact = models.ForeignKey(ContactInternal, related_name='fk_contactinternal_sysapp', null=True, verbose_name="Internal Contact",blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

It is working fine for most of the case. e.g. when I make a change to ContactInternal, a new version is made to SysApp. Pretty happy with how it works.

However if I delete a record linked from `SysApp.internalcontact`, no version is created for SysApp.

Actually all I want to achieve is to get a timestamp of the last modified date of SysApp and by which user(don't need to rollback). I want to know

```
'When Peter delete a John from ContactInternal on 26th Feb, it will show Peter updated SysApp on 26th Feb'
```

How can I do it with `django-reversion`? Or is there another way to achieve this?

- Note: There is another field in SysApp which is M2M I would like to achieve the same result too.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

There are 3 steps needed:
1) add 'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in settings.py
2) create a pre_delete signal function to look up the SysApp object
3) explicit call save() for the SysApp obj

Some explaination:
1) By adding the middleware any changes to your models will be added to revision history
2) use a pre_delete signal to find the SysApp object (the parent)
3) call save() to force django-reversion to create a revision

Some references:
django-reversion documentation: http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html
quick example using signal: http://www.koopman.me/2015/01/django-signals-example/